# How to avoid Same Date?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_FS_InsertMrpDetails]
   @date datetime,
   @feedtype varchar(50),
   @rateperkg float,
   @rateper50kg float,
   @updatedby varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN   

 if exists(select * from K_FS_GenerateDcno where date = @date)
 begin 
 select '1' as status
 end
 else
 begin

insert into K_FS_FeedMrpDetails([date],feedtype,rateperkg,rateper50kg,
updatedby,updatedon) values (@date,@feedtype,@rateperkg,@rateper50kg,
@updatedby,getdate())

select '2' as status

END
```

I have 9 rows ,these 9 rows were updated by only one "DATE" if i enter same Date Then it shows "Date Rates Already Exists".. How can i Do this..Please Help Me..

Comment: the "Date Rates Already Exists" is not coming from this procedure. try and find the code that validates the data entered. there might be an insert trigger

Comment: I am using Dynamic GridView in C#.net..I ented 9 Rows of one date..

Comment: i'm only guessing here, so i suspect that there is only one rate per day per feedtype allowed. this is what would make sense to me. check the constraints on table `K_FS_FeedMrpDetails` or other validation code that gives you "Date Rates Already Exist". also check if the data you are trying to enter already exists in the table and requires removing first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with this kind of logic and datetime. If you know the date you want to insert, what you have is sufficient as long as you are not providing a time i.e C# DateTime.Now vs DateTime.Today.

Brett is 100% correct that you create a unique constraint. This will prevent you from ending up in a duplicates situation and assist in debugging why it occurred. It will also assist the SQL Server engine in its existence checks.

You could also use the rows affected value for your status for performance reasons. E.g.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[K_FS_InsertMrpDetails]....
SELECT @date...
FROM [dbo].[K_FS_InsertMrpDetails]
WHERE (NOT (EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 
                  FROM [dbo].[K_FS_InsertMrpDetails] 
                  WHERE date = @date))

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT + 1 AS Status
```

This statement could output parameter but for this scenario, I wouldn't say its exactly required.

Note:- I typed this outside of SQL, if I missed something, let me know.